# NodeJS err-ssl-protocol-error in http server

Tags: node.js, express, ssl

I've http server and i don't know why it doesn't run;

index.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = (global.app = express());
const helmet = require("helmet");
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = (global.io = require("socket.io")(server));
const config = require("./config.js");

//Middleware
app.use(helmet());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

require("./socket")(io);
require("./router")(app);

server.listen(config.PORT, () => console.log(`Listen on port ${config.PORT}...`));
```

router file:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/../public/main")));
  app.use("/board/:id", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/../public/paint")));
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/../", "/public/404/404.html"));
  });
};
```

Chrome show errors:

```
GET https://10.0.1.55:5000/board/jsdbf/style.css net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
GET https://10.0.1.55:5000/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

for all js, css and imgs. index.html is loaded corectly.

Comment: You are trying to access the server with HTTPS but you have no HTTPS configured on the server. Use `http://...` instead of `https://...` to access the server.

Comment: Yesterday same code worked fine :/ Logs from Firefox: http: Content Security Policy: Failed to process unknown directive "script-src-attr"
Content Security Policy: The page settings blocked the loading of an "inline" resource ("script-src"). fingerprint-protection.js: 286: 17
Failed to load for "script" with source "http://10.0.1.55:5000/socket.io/socket.io.js". 10.0.1.55:5000:31:1
Failed to load for "script" with source "http://10.0.1.55:5000/script.js". 10.0.1.55:5000:32:1

Comment: Content Security Policy: The page settings blocked the loading of an "inline" resource ("script-src"). fingerprint-protection.js: 286: 17

Comment: The errors from your last two comment have nothing to do with SSL and thus have nothing to do with your original question.

Comment: I think that  `app.use(helmet());` forces the call in HTTPS

Answer (score 2):

I am not a 100% expert in Content Security Policy but I noticed something.

As [Benjamin Lemoine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3997582/benjamin-lemoine) pointed out, the `net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` problem appears when using helmet (`app.use(helmet())`). I do not think that the solution is to not use helmet at all because it provides security for the application.

After performing a brute force of all helmet [middlewares](https://helmetjs.github.io/) (contentSecurityPolicy, dnsPrefetchControl, expectCt, frameguard, etc), I found out that `contentSecurityPolicy` was creating the error. The [WDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests) docs say that the ***upgrade-insecure-requests** directive instructs user agents to treat all of a site's insecure URLs (those served over HTTP) as though they have been replaced with secure URLs (those served over HTTPS)*.

So to solve the problem and use helmet at the same time I changed this:

```
app.use( helmet() );
```

to this:

```
app.use( helmet() );
app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
  directives: {
    ...defaultDirectives,
  },
}));
```

This way I am still using helmet but the CSP directives are not forcing HTPP to HTTPS. Please keep in mind that the **upgrade-insecure-requests** directive should be set on production environments.

Comment: `app.use(helmet({
  contentSecurityPolicy: false
}));` worked for me using helmet@4.6.0.

Answer (score 1):

Helmet is a package that adds content-security-policies and response headers to your API replies. The content-security-policy header was set to a default value, which contained a CSP header of "upgrade-insecure-requests." The queries for the style files were redirected from http to https as a result of this net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

When applying helmet to your application, you may overcome the problem by adding the following logic.

```
const cspDefaults = helmet.contentSecurityPolicy.getDefaultDirectives();
delete cspDefaults['upgrade-insecure-requests'];

app.use(helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: { directives: cspDefaults }
}));
```